# How to get average days taken from a mysql datetime fields in php?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, average

I have a mysql database in which i have two `datetime` fields, one is `start_date` another one is `end_date`. So lets say **scorer1** have a `start_date` and `end_date` | similarly **scorer2** have a `start_date` and `end_date`.

Now how can i get the average **days** taken by all the **scorers**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the difference between the dates with mysql:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date)) as difference_in_days, COUNT(id) as total_rows FROM table
```

This will give you the total days difference, and the total rows it applies to.

Then once you've pulled that from the DB, use some PHP to work out the average:

```
$average = $row['difference_in_days'] / $row['total_rows'];
```